# Applying Fundamental theorem of calculus problem

Tags: calculus

In this link provided is a question about the Fundemental Theorem of Calculus since I don't know how to use LaTeX. I somehow can't get the right answer, I'm using the chain rule and everything but still getting it wrong

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ig1nt.png)

$$F(x)=\int_0^{x^3} 4\sin \pi t^2dt$$

Find $F(0)$ and $F'(x)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interesting thing is that what you put for your answer is right. There must be some formatting issue with your homework software. Have you tried something like changing the "pi" to a "Pi"?

Comment: Thanks it worked, thats really stupid how it does that

Answer (score 5):

$$F(x)=\int_0^{x^3} 4\sin \pi t^2dt$$

Actually you do not need to do the integration for it.

Notice when $x=0$, $x^3=0$, you integrate from $0$ to $0$, that should get $F(0)=0$

By chain rule, $F'(x) = 4\sin\pi(x^3)^2 \cdot 3x^2=12x^2\sin\pi x^6$

So your answer is correct.